# Running as android application in Eclipse - nothing happens

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I have a simple app.

Have textView with "Hello World!". Run once and it worked.

Now I changed text value to "Hello ME!", and I cannot "recompile" aka run with "Run as android app",.. Just nothing happnes.

If I click "Green play button" to start app, It just runs previous app with text "Hello World!".. Which means I can't "recompile".. Coming from C# waters, that is why I am saying recompile.

Any suggestions?

Got this error once:

> [2013-02-22 19:32:35 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>   java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Comment: Are you using an emulator? try restarting your emulator.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project? (from Project->Clean) ?

Comment: Did you change it in XML? If so, try modifying one of the java files, then hitting debug again. Adding and removing a space does the trick for me.

Comment: Same problem here.
Eclipse and Android is a joke...no errors, no degug messages, nothing.
It's just randomly works when it decides too.

Answer (score 2):

i have faced this problem many time . and when it occurs i do this 
1.open your emulator
2. go to settings>application>yourapp
3.uninstall your app
RECOMPILE
it works for me whenever this problem occur
if its not! then delete your emulator and create a new one restart eclipse!
:) it'll work

Answer (score 2):

it always happens when you run your application immediately right after your android is loaded, you must wait until your application is loaded by android, do not run it by yourself (like open menu and run your aplication), just be patient, but if it doesn't run than you need to restart your application.

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked: http://lesleyharrison.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/solution-for-android-emulator-starts-but-app-doesnt-run/

Slight difference for me is that I checked, "ask everytime which avd to use".. So now I run run configurator->run always when I make change, and select my avd.